# Why are there clj and cljs folders in my lein re-frame template?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

Why are there clj and cljs folders in my lein re-frame template as below? And why do they both include files called `.core` that appear to use the same namespaces? I've been told this is the place to start when learning re-frame, but I cannot find any explanations of why the templates are setup the way they are or created including the content they include.

There is no explanation for any of the boilerplate or code that comes with any lein template which make them very hard to use for beginners.

[image]

Comment: It assumes that you're using clojure for the backend. You can delete that directory if you're only using clojurescript with some other backend (or have your backend in another repo). Usually there's also a cljc directory for files that can be used by both clojurescript and clojure. Also if you're just getting started, I highly recommend using reagent or rum over reframe or om. The latter two are really geared towards big SPAs with complex data management. Reagent is less powerful but much easier to get started with.

Comment: Thanks, I am very familiar with large javascript applications that use redux, I am just struggling to break in to the world of ClojureScript because of the complex tooling and thin on the ground documentation!

Comment: Ok. Just know two things: 1. reframe implements it's own pub/sub architecture for state and data management. It's pretty standard as far as such things go, but not necessarily what you're used to from react/redux. 2. The documentation and tooling is actually pretty good *except* (last I checked) it's generally geared towards *Clojure* developers rather than *Javascript* developers (which is admittedly a problem).

Comment: Ok! Thanks... I see. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setup is used to separate Clojure Backend code from the ClojureScript frontend. It isn't actually necessary and I don't particularly recommend it but I can explain its history and why you'd want to do it.

For the ClojureScript side it really doesn't matter at all.

When builing a Clojure Backend you will often deploy in some "uberjar" or "uberwar" setup. This means that all source files and dependencies are packed into one single `.jar` file (basically just a zip file). This is typically done by including all files from a specified set of directories, so it would include `src/clj` but not `src/cljs`. If everything is in one directory it would add the `.cljs` files as well although they are never used by the Clojure backend. So in essence it just makes your "uberjar" bigger. It is not an important optimizations but some people prefer to keep things lean and clean.

In addition some developers just prefer to separate the code this way. In this case the template authors did.

Answer (score 2):

**One answer:**

As the comments point out, some projects develop the backend code (Clojure) and the frontend code (ClojureScript) in the same project repo.  I think this is a mistake as it can easily lead to confusion and entanglement (esp. if using lein to start both projects simultaneously).  IMHO it is better to keep both front- and back-end parts in separate repositories.  I would also strongly recommend using *figwheel-main* and the Clojure deps build tool for the CLJS code.

**Another answer:**

For CLJS code, any macros have to be defined in an "earlier" compilation stage.  Thus, for namespaces defining macros, you often see files like either `util.clj` or `util.cljc` to define the macro, and then a file like `util.cljs` where the macro is used.

You can find more information below, but it is subtle & confusing:

- https://clojurescript.org/guides/ns-forms
- https://clojurescript.org/about/differences
- https://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2018-08-12-two-file-clojurescript-namespace-pattern.html